# How to access a single element from a return of multiple types?

Tags: solidity

I have the following function:

```
 function doSomething(uint _someArg) public returns(bool, uint) {
     // Do something
     return (true, 0);
 }
```

How can I access afterwords only for exaple the "true" or the number of that function return:

I tried:

```
doSomething[0]
```

or

```
doSomething[1]
```

but did not work obviously becasue is not a list, but the elements do not have an identifier,

so how can I access each separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```js
(bool b, uint n) = doSomething(args);
```

If You don't need one of the params, You can omit them by leaving it empty and separating it with comma:

```js
(, uint n) = doSomething(args);
```

Or:

```js
(bool b,) = doSomething(args);
```

A function that returns multiple values basically returns a tuple, and we use a syntax similar to the tuple to get the values individually.